# ASP.NET repository get id after insert

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can i get id after `insert()` command. Here is the code.

```
private readonly IRepository<ShoppingCart> _shoppingCartRepository;
public ShoppingCartBL(IRepository<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartRepository)
    {
        _shoppingCartRepository = shoppingCartRepository;
    }

public int CreateNewShoppingCart(ShoppingCart item)
    {
        if(item==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ShoppingCart Variable");

        this._shoppingCartRepository.Insert(item);
        return this._shoppingCartRepository.Table.Last().Id;
    }
```

This part gives error: `return this._shoppingCartRepository.Table.Last().Id;`

I just need get id of inserted item.

Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have inserted the entity it should be updated so that the property that maps to the primary key in the database has the new PK value.

Like in your case **item.Id** will give you the new Id

Answer (score 2):

This also worked: `return this._shoppingCartRepository.Table.ToList().Last().Id;`